# Bootstrap Carousel Changes Images But Won't Slide

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, bootstrap-4

Everything works in My bootstrap carousel, except the slide effect doesn't happen even though I've added the "slide" CSS tag. The images quickly change; they don't ***slide***.

Couple notes:

- I'm using bootstrap v4.3.1.
- I used the same mark-up as the bootstrap documentation.
- My bootstrap javascript file is after the jquery file.

Any ideas?

Here is my HTML.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en-us">
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/plugins/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col">
                <div class="row">
                    <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" data-interval="4000">
                        <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                            <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                            <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
                            <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
                        </ol>

                        <div class="carousel-inner">
                            <div class="carousel-item active">
                                <img src="images/slider-1.png" class="d-block w-100" />
                            </div>
                            <div class="carousel-item">
                                <img src="images/slider-2.png" class="d-block w-100" />
                            </div>
                            <div class="carousel-item">
                                <img src="images/slider-3.png" class="d-block w-100" />
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="carousel-controls">
                            <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
                                <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                                <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
                            </a>
                            <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
                                <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                                <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

<script src="/shared/js/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="/plugins/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

</html>
```

Comment: Any errors in your console?

Comment: They only error is "Failed to load resource: favicon.ico the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)". Which I don't know why I'm getting that error, but don't think it has anything to do with the slider?

Comment: Your HTML is invalid when you place the script tags outside the body. Of note, the `<link>` and `<img>` tags do not use and do not need a closing slash in HTML and never have.

Comment: Changing images, js & CSS files with the Bootstrap default ones, your code works well. Could you please create a working example to see your bug? https://codepen.io/ReSedano/pen/oNNmxzN

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <title>repl.it</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col">
                <div class="row">
                    <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" data-interval="4000">
                        <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                            <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                            <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
                            <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
                        </ol>

                        <div class="carousel-inner">
                            <div class="carousel-item active">
                                <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2013/07/12/17/47/test-pattern-152459__340.png" class="d-block w-100" />
                            </div>
                            <div class="carousel-item">
                                <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2013/07/12/17/47/test-pattern-152459__340.png" class="d-block w-100" />
                            </div>
                            <div class="carousel-item">
                                <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2013/07/12/17/47/test-pattern-152459__340.png" class="d-block w-100" />
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="carousel-controls">
                            <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
                                <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                                <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
                            </a>
                            <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
                                <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                                <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
  </body>
  <footer>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </footer>
</html>
```

I used your code in the `<body> </body>` section in repl.it and it works but there are some sizing issues tho. copied the code to here you can run it and see for yourself :) It slides as well

Edit*

I see you are inserting the carousel into a row and col, don't think you should do that but if you want to you need to make the correct size adjustments else the carousel will break the row and col each time it slides.

remove this section in your code inorder to make your carousel work properly

```
<div class="row">
            <div class="col">
                <div class="row">
```

Also, I think the reason why yours did not work is because of your HTML structure, and your bootstrap js and CSS CDNS wasn't imported correctly.

getbootstrap.com has a starter/Boiler template that you can always use with the correct imports, layout etc.

See here 
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/getting-started/introduction/#starter-template

Comment: This is commentary on the issue not a solution to the problem.

Comment: Now that you edited it with a solution, it's a proper answer.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but none of your suggestions worked including: 1) removing extra divisions (and that shouldn't matter), 2) using the starter template with my "<div id=MyCarousel></div>", 3) using your code as-is, 4) using your code with my images, 5) using my code with your css and js links.